# Bind Webgrid using JQuery failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

Hi I am using `webgrid` this time.and Binding `json` data using `JQuery`. My `ajax call script` providing data but I am unable to get it some how.**I have gone thorugh all the questions available here but nothing worked.** Look at the components and tell me what is wrong.

This is the web grid

```
<div id="GridContent">
            @{
                var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 15, selectionFieldName: "Id", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "GridContent", canSort: true);
            }
            @grid.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
            htmlAttributes:"grid",
            emptyRowCellValue: "--",
            headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
            selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(columnName: "CenterId", header: "Id"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "CenterName", header: "CenterName"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "CenterCode", header: "CenterCode"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "Address", header: "Address"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "EmailId", header: "EmailId"),
            grid.Column(format: @<a id="EditCenter" class="fa-anchor" data-id="@item.CenterId">Edit</a>),
            grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink((string)"Delete", "DeleteCenter", new { CenterId = item.CenterId }, new { id = "DeleteCenter", onclick = "return confirm('Are You Sure Want To Delete The Center Data?');" }))))
        </div>
```

**and here is my ajax call for binding the data on dropdown change.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ListType").change(function () {
        var webgrid;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ListTypeUrl,
            data: { id: $("#ListType").val() },
            datatype:'html',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#GridContent").html(result);
                alert("Success");

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("On select Failed " + result);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Here is Controller method for getting JSON Results

```
public JsonResult GetCenterList(int id)
        {
            List<CenterDetails> cd = objDal.GetCenterListItem(id.ToString(), Session["AgentId"].ToString());


            return Json(cd,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
public List<CenterDetails> GetCenterListItem(string type, string AgentId)
        {
            XElement xl = new XElement("root"
                , new XAttribute("OType", "Select")
                , new XAttribute("Target", "CenterList")
                , new XElement("Type",Convert.ToInt32(type))
                , new XElement("AgentId", AgentId));
            ds = ExecuteDataSet("Sp_CenterAction", CommandType.StoredProcedure, new MySqlParameter("@xml", xl.ToString()));
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            drc = dt.Rows;
            List<CenterDetails> objList = new List<CenterDetails>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in drc)
            {
                objList.Add(new CenterDetails
                {
                    CenterId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["cm_Id"].ToString()),
                    CenterName = dr["cm_Name"].ToString(),
                    CenterCode = dr["cm_CenterCode"].ToString(),
                    Address = dr["cm_Address"].ToString(),
                    EmailId = dr["cm_EmailId"].ToString()
                });
            }

            return objList;

        }
```

Comment: Where is your code for _Binding json data using JQuery_? All you have shown is an ajax call that returns a partial view and overwrites the contents of your grid

Comment: @StephenMuecke have you any solution for this.

Comment: It not clear what your wanting to do here. Is that ajax call calling the `GetCenterList()` method (we have no idea what `url: ListTypeUrl` evaluates to)? And that code shows your replacing the grid with a partial view.

Comment: yeah ... this method calls the controller action and I have checked the data is perfect but the problem is about rendering that to View page... @StephenMuecke

Comment: You ajax call is expecting a partial view. Your `GetCenterList()` method needs to return a partial view that renders your `@grid.GetHtml(...)` code based on the `List<CenterDetails>` your getting. (minus the enclosing `<div id="GridContent">` element.